# Best website/blog to learn objective, pros&cons of design pattern with C# code

Tags: c#, design-patterns

As I am going to improve my skills, please refer some links which explains about design pattern objective, pros&cons of design pattern with C# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DoFactory.com](http://dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx) is the best one to learn `Design-Patterns`. Here every patterns are explained with one structural and one real-world example, along with the `UML class diagram`

Comment: in addition, O'Reilly's C# 3.0 Design Patterns is great for all the same reasons (4.0 is probably just as good)  I know its not a web site but you can pick it up on Amazon for like 5 bucks...http://www.amazon.com/3-0-Design-Patterns-Judith-Bishop/dp/059652773X/ref=pd_sim_b_2

Comment: ya...I heard `O'Reilly's` books are nice! but I didn't red any books of them...will check soon.